# How to have Photo screensaver display across multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, screensaver

I have 3 monitors. I'm using the default Win7 "Photos" screensaver. I have the rightmost monitor my Primary monitor.

But when the screensaver starts, it displays only on my left monitor. This does not make any sense. How can I get the screensaver Photos to display on my right monitor (or all 3)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this response by Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/photo-screensaver-with-multiple-displays/3aab4f4b-8f69-400b-94ff-95bf294ef492), this is working as intended.

Comment: Yes, but that's where the Primary monitor is showing the pictures. My Primary is not.

Comment: I agree with you. I found your question because I have the same issue, but its pretty clear from the response that I linked to that Microsoft does not consider this to be a bug.